# How to use git-extras on windows(PortableGit)

Tags: git, msysgit

the project : https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras

how to use it on windows(PortableGit)

Answer (score 4):

Isn't using MinGW a bit overkilled for this?
I have not worked with the PortableGit version but this works for me with MsysGit:

- Go to their Github reporitory (https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras);
- **Downalod** the zip/tarball from the latest tag (or master if you feel risky);
- **Copy** the content from their "**bin/**" directory to MsysGit's "**libexec/git-core/**" directory. Don't worry, nothing shall be overwritten.
- If you want the *documentation*, **copy** their "**man/*.html**" files to MsysGit's "**doc/git/html/**" directory. Once again, nothing shall be overwritten.
- If you use the "*Git Bash*" environment, you can **append** the content of their "**etc/bash_completion**" file in MsysGit's "**etc/git-completion.bash**" file;

Wish this helps!

Comment: Note that some commands might not work due to missing core commands.

Comment: Re-edit: Note that some commands might not work due to missing Linux/Unix core commands provided by MsysGit.
By exemple, "git alias" won't work due to the "colrm" command which might be replaced manually with an alternative command.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a PowerShell version of git-extras at https://github.com/raeffs/git-extras-windows

Answer (score 3):

If you have mingw installed in your windows machine or if you have cygwin, then the one liner mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/blob/master/Readme.md) file should work. You don't need to specify `sudo` at the last part highlighted in bold and italics below:

One-liner:

`$ (cd /tmp && git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras.git && cd git-extras &&`***`sudo`***`make install)`

Comment: so it didn't support msysgit?

Comment: By default, msysgit doesn't come with the `make` tool. But you may try by installing GnuWin32 from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ and then try the one liner.