# How do I cp a file in Git Bash to a new directory without having to mv it?

Tags: git, github, terminal, zsh, git-bash

I have two files (index.html and style.css) in a directory called Bootcamp inside a folder (or directory) within Bootcamp called code-refactoring. I need to push index.html and style.css to GitHub so I'm assuming I first need to cp these two files into my GitHub repo directory before checking the GitHub repo directory git status.

How do I cp those two files from one directory to the other without having to use the mv command?

Comment: Use `cp` instead of `mv`?

Comment: yes but how do I cp a file to a different directory instead of to the same directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy multiple files from a different directory using cp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915822/how-to-copy-multiple-files-from-a-different-directory-using-cp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+copy+file+cp

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

After seeing your comment, I assume you want to know on how to cp to different folders. There are many ways to it. I will list down one example.

cd to your source directory, and from there you could give the destination's folder path. If you are unsure, you can always give an absolute path to destination folder.

```
$ cd PATH/TO/SOURCE/FOLDER
$ cp FILENAME PATH/TO/DESTINATION/FOLDER
```

**ORIGINAL**

cp -> will make a copy of the file/folder to destination path, preserving the original file.

```
$ cp SOURCE DEST
```

mv -> will move the file/folder to destination path, removing the original file.

```
$ mv SOURCE DEST
```

Copying a file to the destination folder will create an untracked file. 
To push the new file, you have to stage the file (git add) and commit it (git commit).

```
$ git add FILE_NAME
$ git commit -m "Commit message"
$ git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy files in git repo with keeping all git history - use git-cp command

https://www.mankier.com/1/git-cp
https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/main/bin/git-cp

> `git cp {{path/to/file}} {{path/to/new_file}}`

how to install on win32: [How to use git-extras on windows(PortableGit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602024/how-to-use-git-extras-on-windowsportablegit)